# MongoDB PHP Aggregation empty results with date ($lte, $gte) in $match

Tags: php, mongodb

I've the following Aggregation:

```
$pipeline = array(
    array('$match' => array(
        'matchDate' => array(
            '$lte' => $dateEnd, // DateTime object
            '$gte' => $dateStart // DateTime object
         )
    )),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$sport',
        'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
    ))
);

$m = new \MongoClient('localhost');
$c = $m->selectDB('test_database')->selectCollection('Match');
$t = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
```

This aggregation will return an empty Result.

If I run the aggregation on my MongoDB directly, it works without problems and gives the expected results.
Here is the native query.

```
db.Match.runCommand({
  "aggregate": "Match", 
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$match": { 
        "matchDate": {
          "$lte": new ISODate("2015-10-07T23:59:59+02:00"), 
          "$gte": new ISODate("2015-10-06T00:00:00+02:00") 
        } 
      } 
    }, 
    { 
      "$group": { "_id": "$sport", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } 
    }
]});
```

The problem occurs only with aggregation. Find queries with date ($lte, $gte) works also without problems.

Here is an example document.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5613bbb79042ad801f0041ab"),
  "sport": ObjectId("5613bbb79042ad801f0041a8"),
  "matchDate": new Date("2015-09-26T13:45:00+0200")
}
```

Has someone an idea whats happen here?

I'm Using

MongoDB Support 1.6.11

PHP 5.6.13

MongoDB 3.0.6

Comment: Your constructed dates will not be valid. Check your date input's and show the code where you define them if you still have the problem.

Comment: My input is a DateTime object. What would be the correct input?

Comment: [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll work with MongoDate.

```
$pipeline = array(
    array('$match' => array(
        'matchDate' => array(
            '$lte' => new MongoDate($dateEnd->getTimestamp()),
            '$gte' => new MongoDate($dateStart->getTimestamp())
         )
    )),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$sport',
        'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
    ))
);

$m = new \MongoClient('localhost');
$c = $m->selectDB('test_database')->selectCollection('Match');
$t = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Thanks @Blakes Seven